# How to pass id to javascript?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm working on a codeigniter site right now. In my db I have a project and some project_logs.

I would like to check how many logs each project has and display it in the span of each project. But how can i pass the ID of each project in to the javascript?

I tried doing this in my script:

```
setInterval(
    function (){
    var ID = $(".trial").attr("data-id");
    var el = $('span#trial-' + ID);
    $(el).load("<? echo base_url()?>/projects_logs/checkMessage/" + ID);
}, 1000);
```

My View:

```
<ul class="dropdown-slider">
<? foreach($roster->latest->result_object() as $project) { ?>
     <li class="trial" data-id="<?=$project->id?>">
           <a href="<? echo base_url();?>projects/<?=$project->id?>">
               <?=$project->title?><span id="trial-<?=$project->id?>" data-id="<?=$project->id?>"></span>
           </a>
      </li>
<? } ?> 
</ul>
```

At my controller, it will return the ID of the project to check if the script works but later on it will execute a query that counts how many logs the project has.Right now nothing happened.

I'm not familiar with javascript and only learn it through google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many functions in your JavaScript:

```
setInterval(
    function (){function checkMessage(){
      // ...
}, 1000);
```

The end brace in the above ends "checkMessage()" which you never invoke. Simply delete "function checkMessage(){" from the above, and you should have something computed:

```
setInterval(
    function (){
      // ...
}, 1000);
```

Note that your JavaScript code operates on the first element in the list and does not operate on all the elements. Using jQuery, you would use .each() to operate across all the elements in the list.

In the future, a good way to debug these is to:

1. Look at the JavaScript error console to see if there are any obvious errors.
2. Inspect the DOM to ensure it looks like what you expect.
3. Use console.log() to make sure that your JavaScript is actually invoked.
4. Use console.log() to see what the intermediate computations are.

Comment: Ohh. that was my mistake. Also my url was misspelled so it doesn't do anything. Now all I need to do is to study how to use .each() to traverse across the <li> elements. Thanks for the help by the way, I might be stuck with this problem without your help. :D